# Folders not created using mkdirs() in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I am creating folders using `mkdirs()` method. Before that, i am also checking if folder is already present or not. if not then only create. It works fine almost all devices but somehow its not creating in some devices.

I also checked runtime permission and storage access framework before creating folders. its all good still it does not create folders. Below is the sample path of creating folders:

```
Path: /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/TestFolder
```

Here, `/storage/emulated/0/` is internal storage path. After that i am creating two folders using below code:

```
val folder = File(Path)
if (!folder.exists()) {
   if(!folder.mkdirs()){
     Log.e("MyActivity","Folder not created")
   }
}
```

I also tried using below code:

```
val folder = File(Path)
if (!folder.parentFile.exists()) {
   if(!folder.parentFile.mkdirs()){
     Log.e("MyActivity","Folder not created")
   }
}
```

But still not working.

Comment: How are you generating `Path`? Are you hardcoding `/storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, hardcoding. Because it was my initial path for application.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`getFilesDir()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), you should never assume a hardcoded installation or directory path - you should only be using relative paths compared to one of the [storage directories](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)

Comment: Then why its working for almost all devices and not working in few devices?

Comment: @SagarMaiyad: Perhaps those device manufacturers changed the path of the external storage root. Perhaps those devices are running Android Q, where you do not have read/write access to the external storage root by default (once your `targetSdkVersion` is 29 or higher). Due to the latter, I strongly recommend that you switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and stop thinking in terms of files, at least for Android 5.1+ devices. As a bonus, the user now has the ability to control where your content goes.

Comment: @CommonsWare This problem also happens in internal storage. not only external storage. and it also happens in lower versions than Android Q. Second thing, My application also supported for kitkat version. So, i can't switch to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad: "This problem also happens in internal storage. not only external storage" -- not according to your question. You hard-coded `/storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/TestFolder`, and that is on what [the Android SDK refers to as external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "i can't switch to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for Android 5.1+, and use something else based off of `Environment` methods and the filesystem for older devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare  You hard-coded /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/TestFolder -- I mentioned that this is sample path.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad: And that sample path is on what the Android SDK refers to as external storage. Also, in your comments, you said that you were hard-coding this value.

Comment: You can't hard code paths on Android. Ever. Everything needs to be a relative path from one of the storage directories as that is the only guaranteed consistent solution across devices.